# How to pin to top in a TableView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cell, favorite

I have a `tableView` with hundreds of cells. I want to add a feature to pin to top favorite cells, for example by swipe.  Is there a way to do that? Or is it easier to have a different `tableView` with favorite cells?

Comment: Just use sections and add the favorites to the first section

Answer (score 0):

Section for this.

Add your favorites to view, you can create it using storyboard or programmatically using following code. If you use storyboard, create and make a reference to the tableViewController and just return in this code.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
{
   // create and return yourView
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you be more specific? how can I add the favorites to the header section?